# Tips for a language spoken by a guinea pig-like race

Tags: aliens, conlang

The most advanced race in my custom universe is a race of guinea pig-like aliens. They are short and have titanium bones, considering their homeworld has a gravity of 1.7 g. The nervous system features four brains which allow them to engage in a form of intellectual multitasking and they have four ears, one pair can sense infrasounds since they are a prey species whose predators use infrasounds for communication. I want their language grammar to look alien, but not too hard for humans in order to learn it and the language to sound weird, but very pleasant to the human ear. What are my grammatically and phonologically constraints when creating a language for this race?

Comment: I imagine the downvotes and close votes are because this is an extremely broad question - I don't think any of the details you've provided actually narrow down the possibilities of what this language could be like.

Comment: Are you going to be constructing this language? Will you have your readers actually read this constructed language? If "No" and/or "No", what is the point of this question? What are you actually after? Also you are being **much** too broad here... the description "Guinea pig-like alien" does not in any way provide information that allows to find any such constraints that you ask for; it is **much** too vague and open to opinions and interpretations.

Comment: I would advise looking a bit more into what conlangs need. First of all, what is the purpose of this language? What do your creatures sound like in general? What do you want their language to sound like? Do you want real-world humans to be able to speak it? These are just the basics, but I feel like you want to see what grammatical constructs would arise, in which case edit your question to reflect that. Even then, I still feel this may be too broad a question for this site.

Comment: They will sound precisely like bananas, if bananas had six pairs of lungs; only they would speak with fewer adjectives and more epithets, and a Southern drawl.

Comment: Wow. the censors are at it again. They don't like a question, they put it on hold. I am beginning to wonder if they are not multiples of the same entity. This is a reasonable question, with specific answers, based on biology. Small creatures do not tend to have deep base voices. Small lungs mean short vocalizations. More like a chirping language. Squirrels use chirps to communicate with each other. We have broken the code.

Comment: ctd Humans can mimic to an extent squirrels will respond. [Learn to speak squirrel in four easy lessons](https://www.washingtonpost.com/local/learn-to-speak-squirrel-in-four-easy-lessons/2012/04/09/gIQAV8Jr6S_story.html?utm_term=.3edb59d83206) Is squirrel talk alien enough for you? It should give you a good lead.

Comment: This question is principally too broad because of the OP asking for grammar constraints.  Inventing an entire language is well beyond the scope of this site.  And lest anyone object... that's exactly what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @JBH It is obvious the OP is looking for leads, not specifics. I think we do a valuable service if we can point in a direction to pursue, not necessarily an exact, specific answer. Is the intent to write the novel, or dictate the details, or just point in a direction that the answer might lie in? Do we want to kill the creativity, or foster it?

Comment: @JustinThyme, I've contributed to the design of languages.  Have you?  There are no leads or pointers to be given.  It's like suggesting handing someone one or two pieces of a 1,000 piece puzzle makes a substantial difference.  It actually does at the end, after the many rules and assumptions have first been developed, but it's meaningless at the beginning.  We certainly don't want to kill people's creativity, but there are also limits to what this site can do on a pracitcal level.  This question crossed that line.

Comment: @JBH So you want the question to fit only your expertise, so you can give a specific answer? Is this a community of many, or a community of a few? Just because YOU have no leads, nor can conceive of any... I GAVE a lead - specific research on the language of squirrels. Concrete, specific, and potentially useful.

Comment: @JustinThyme, I want the question to fit within the limits expressed by the rules, which the OP should have read.  Nothing more, nothing less.  Stack Exchange is not a forum.  It was designed to provide specific answers to specific questions.  The OP isn't asking for the simplistic interpretation of the chips of squirrels, he/she's asking for a fully fledged language of a his/her universe's "most advanced race."  Perhaps the question is about non-technological squirrels, but that only proves the question is not well enough defined.

Comment: ctd The reference contained squirrel phonemes, how the squirrel produced them, words, and meanings of those words, It was an example of very non-human communication that we could interpret and mimic. I suggest that, indeed, it was a 'tip for a language that a guinea pig-like race' could be built around, just like the OP requested, complete with 'grammatically and phonologically constraints'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66500/discussion-between-jbh-and-justin-thyme).

Comment: @JustinThyme One thing, and this is _the_ reason I voted to close this ASAP, Grammar has no basis in biology, it's a social construct within language there are exactly zero concrete answers to a grammar construction question dealing in theoretical, as opposed to historical or extant, languages. Also as it was written when I first saw it I couldn't make any sense of the question, and I still can't.

Comment: No language sounds pleasant across all cultural/societal boundaries in the modern world, even in English there are certain accents and dialects I love, French Canadian for example and there are others where I want to tell the speaker to stop the mutilation already. I like the sound of Italian and Portuguese but not French or Spanish, my wife and I share the same English dialect but have completely different tastes in accents and foreign languages. The Ultimate Point: What one person thinks is senseless noise others will think is ever so cute and nice _and vice versa_.

Comment: @Ash Perhaps this will clarify the link between human speech and biology. Syntax, of course, is grammar. 
 [On the Evolutionary Biology of Speech and Syntax](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-017-2039-7_21)

Comment: @JustinThyme The second sentence of that article says "fully developed human speech and syntax are species-specific" you cannot extrapolate a language from an anatomy lesson. Language evolves because of local history, period.

Comment: @Ash The proof is in the pudding. Did the OP get anything useful or usable from the conversation?

Comment: It has already been done.  -  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hrQdi7UGjvU

Comment: I was going to suggest that it be moved to conlang.se, but then saw how very old the question is... Carry on.

Answer (score 3):

**Honestly you have no constraints**

Except for the limitation based by their lingual physiology. The guinea pig is physically incapable of forming English words. Their language could easily be a logical order of the squeaks they make or with their intellect they could make translators to speak whatever language they want.